# handling release branches in gitflow

Tags: git, branching-and-merging, git-flow

The company I work for is using gitflow.

We follow a branch-per-feature approach where individual features are implemented, tested and then PR'd into develop. When it comes time for a release we create a release branch off develop - we trigger a build on the release branch and deploy this to a TEST environment. There might be some integration defects due to the multiple feature branches that were merged into develop. These are resolved directly against the release branch. Once we're happy with the state of the release branch we deploy (the exact *same* build that was signed-off by QA) to PROD.

At this stage we need to get our release branch code back to develop and into master, which are both protected branches. Assuming there were some commits against the release branch, we need to do 2 PRs i.e. one for release->develop and one for release->master.

Couple questions:

1. How do people review commits directly against a release branch? We
   *could* PR back to develop before the actual release, but this seems a bit out of order to me.
2. How do people approach gettting a release branch
   merged into develop AND master. The PR to develop would just be
   commits that were made directly against the release branch, while
   the PR to master would also include all the features that were
   already PRd into develop. The PR to master seems a bit obsolete.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr:** Ideally you should not need a code review when performing routine Git Flow branch merges. Instead you would make sure all commits into the Git Flow shared branches are code reviewed. Note this solution answers both of your questions.

**Details:**
In your example, merging `release` into `master`, or `release` into `develop` (ideally) would not need human intervention, and could theoretically be automated<sup>1</sup>. In order to achieve that though, you do need to code review all commits that go into `release`, meaning you need to tweak this part of your workflow:

> There might be some integration defects due to the multiple feature branches that were merged into develop. These are resolved **directly** against the release branch.

If you create feature branches off of `release` and PR them into the `release` branch with a normal code review, then later when it's time to merge `release` into another shared Git Flow branch you can be assured that all code on the `release` branch has already been code reviewed, and the merge becomes a routine merge that doesn't necessitate an in-depth review.

Many Git SCM tools have the concept of Protected branches, which require a PR be used in order to merge code into them. The recommendation here is in addition to protecting `develop` and `master`, you should also protect your `release` and `hotfix` branches.

**Tip:** when completing a `release` branch, [Git Flow recommends](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/#finishing-a-release-branch) merging the `release` branch into both `master` and `develop`. However, there is a slightly more efficient mechanism which achieves the same *state* but has some added advantages. The tweak is to first merge `release` into `master`, and then merge `master` into `develop`. The benefit of doing this is the new merge commit on `master` will also be on `develop`, which means `develop` is "ahead" of `master`. When it comes time to merge the next `release` branch into `master` it would be fully up to date from a commit ID point of view, meaning you *could* do a fast-forward merge. Of course you'll still merge into `master` using `--no-ff` like Git Flow recommends, but knowing that you *could* fast-forward tells you with certainty that the state of `master` after the merge is identical to the `release` branch you tested. If you don't do it this way, you have to compare the states to make sure you aren't about to blow over a hotfix on `master` that you forgot to merge back into `release` or `develop`. Another minor benefit is that without doing this, if you have multiple releases in a row, the first time you have a `hotfix` you'll be merging a bunch of old merge commits from `master` into `develop` for the first time, and it's sort of confusing to see that.

---

<sup>1</sup> Git Flow shared branch merges can usually be completed automated. Only in the case where there are *non-deterministic* merge conflicts would a human need to get involved. An example of non-deterministic conflicts might be when merging `release` or `master` down to `develop`, where certain files have changed in both branches after the `release` branch was created. Note that some conflicts could be considered *deterministic* and can still be auto-resolved with logic, such as version files that are modified in both branches and the resolution mechanism is known beforehand.